# Check if all rows from query are selected

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this code which is part of an AJAX function where 5 rows are added to `$opslaglimit` each time the user reaches the bottom of the page.

```
$opslaglimit = 5;    
$opslag = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id LIMIT $opslaglimit");
```

I want to make a function, so I can display a message to the user when there are no rows left to collect from the database that matches the query.

I know this can be achieved by making an other query without the LIMIT and then compare the count. This just seems like a bit of code and I want to hear if any of you knows a more simple way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could "hack around it" by checking if the number of results returned are less than the limit requested. That would mean you are at the end. However, you'll get a false positive once out of each N for limit. Just a QUICK hack. I'll offer a real solution later if needed. :)